# System.IO.FileNotFoundException in SimpleData

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, simple.data

I am using Simple Data (1.0.0-rc0) like `Simple.DataDatabase.Default.Licenses.All().ToList<License>()` to get a list of licenses. It works fine and all in my productions environment (VS2010, IIS7.5) but once deployed to live server it throws :

```
   `System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException: Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.GetTypes(RuntimeModule module)
   at System.Reflection.Assembly.GetTypes()
   at System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.AssemblyCatalog.get_InnerCatalog()
   at System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.AssemblyCatalog.GetExports(ImportDefinition definition)
   at System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.AggregateCatalog.GetExports(ImportDefinition definition)
   at System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.CatalogExportProvider.GetExportsCore(ImportDefinition definition, AtomicComposition atomicComposition)
   at System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.ExportProvider.GetExports(ImportDefinition definition, AtomicComposition atomicComposition)
   at System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.AggregateExportProvider.GetExportsCore(ImportDefinition definition, AtomicComposition atomicComposition)
   at System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.ExportProvider.TryGetExportsCore(ImportDefinition definition, AtomicComposition atomicComposition, IEnumerable1& exports)
   at System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.CompositionContainer.GetExportsCore(ImportDefinition definition, AtomicComposition atomicComposition)
   at System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.ExportProvider.GetExports(ImportDefinition definition, AtomicComposition atomicComposition)
   at System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.ExportProvider.GetExportsCore[T](String contractName)
   at Simple.Data.MefHelper.Compose[T](String contractName)
   at Simple.Data.AdapterFactory.DoCreate(String adapterName, IEnumerable1 settings)
   at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary2.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func2 valueFactory)
   at Simple.Data.CachingAdapterFactory.Create(String adapterName, IEnumerable1 settings)
   at Simple.Data.DatabaseOpener.OpenDefaultMethod()
   at Simple.Data.DatabaseOpener.OpenDefault()`

`System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'`
```

The server is running a freshly installed Windows Server 2008 R2.I have been going at this for the last two days without any progress at all. Did I perhaps miss something crucial during server setup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an issue with MEF. One of the assemblies in your bin folder has a reference to Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell, and when MEF tries to do its thing and it can't follow all the references, it throws that error.

This has been the cause of several bug reports recently, and the next release will have a change to the MEF code which will stop it from happening.

As a workaround in the meantime, you can either track down the assembly with the reference and remove it, or put that assembly in the bin folder. I'd recommend the former, since adding that assembly might be the start of a whole chain of adding more and more.

Comment: I managed to track down the 2.0.0.0 version of Visualstudio.Shell and added it to the project as that seemed like the fastest temporarily solution. Greatly appreciate you clarifying the problem for me, thanks a bunch!

Comment: This problem is fixed in Simple.Data 0.17.1.1, which was published to NuGet yesterday. It has not been published in the -pre branch, though.